# Enumerating CPUs in python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, cpu, joblib

I am parallelizing using joblib. I would like to follow progression of each and every CPU. So, I would like to print out the index of the CPU. E.g. if my computer has 8 cores, I would like each process to know its `cpu_index` so I can `print(f"Hi! I am CPU {cpu_index}")`. Ideally, this command will output a number between 0 and 7.

I am unable to find a way to achieve this via cpuinfo. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is not how CPU scheduling works. When a process becomes runnable, it is scheduled on whichever CPU is available at the time, although the OS might try to keep them on the same CPU to optimize cache utilization. There are ways to override this (look up "cpu affinity"), but by default processes can hop around CPUs at the operating system's whim. For your use case, you can just print the process ID instead.

Answer (score 0):

try [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/) package.
It have many usefull functions for your needs like `psutil.cpu_percent(percpu=True) psutil.cpu_percent()`